# sgen.exe build error "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sgen

I am building a solution which contains several solutions. All but one of them build without any problems.  The problematic one emits the following message:

> Error 2   Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve
>   the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.  J:\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1\SGEN MyPlugin1
>
> I turned on the verbose output in Visual Studio and I got the
>   following: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen.exe  /assembly:

I checked the output with FusionLog and everything loaded correctly. This turned out to be a red herring.  I decided to run the build again with the verbosity turned up. I got the following:

> Microsoft (R) Xml Serialization support utility [Microsoft (R) .NET
>   Framework, Version 4.0.30319.17929] Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.   If you would like more help,
>   please type "sgen /?". SGEN : error : Unable to load one or more of
>   the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information. The command exited with code 1. Done executing task
>   "SGen" -- FAILED.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0
>   Tools\sgen.exe /assembly:":\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1.dll" /proxytypes
>   /reference:"J:\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1\packages\FluentValidation.3.4.6.0\lib\Net40\FluentValidation.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"J:\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1\Libraries\Core\bin\Release\Core.dll"
>   /reference:"J:\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1\Libraries\Services\bin\Release\Services.dll"
>   /reference:"J:\MyPlugins\MyPlugin1\Presentation\Web.Framework\bin\Release\Web.Framework.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll"

What is causing this error and how do I fix it short of turning off SGEN?  FYI, I didn't write the code.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is straightforward but hard to find. You must delete the asp.net precompiled folder. Since plugins are dynamically referenced, .NET can't update it's dlls as it would other components.

Answer (score 14):

A great tip that worked for me, taken from here: http://hashtagfail.com/post/5255977780/sgen-loaderexceptions-error

> The reason why this happens is that in Release builds, Visual Studio
>   attempts to generate a serialization assembly containing the types in
>   your solution, to improve XmlSerializer serialization performance,
>   should you choose to serialize your types. **This can be disabled by
>   going to the Build tab of the project properties and setting “Generate
>   serialization assembly” to “Off”.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was a bad reference in the project.  After deleting the DLL from the GAC, it was working fine.  You can find the problem DLL with Fusion Log.  More info [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)